# Saving retrieve data from firestore to my device, on android

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with my app. I am using android studio, Java and Firebase firestore.
I have a floating button that is used to add category, they are being saved in my main activity and firestore as per my wish, however the problem that i face is that when i log out my data disappear. How do i save or make sure this data doesn't disappear?
This is my code, i tried sharedpreference however the problem is still the same.

```java
    private void showAddCategoryDialog() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_category);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        final EditText categoryEditText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.category_edit_text);
        Button addButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        CategoriesAdapter categoriesAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(categoriesList, this);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String categoryName = categoryEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!categoryName.isEmpty()) {
                    List<String> tasksListForCategory = new ArrayList<>();

                    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    if (currentUser != null) {
                        String userId = currentUser.getUid();
                        TaskGroup newGroup = new TaskGroup(categoryName, "groupId", categoryName, tasksListForCategory, Collections.singletonList(R.drawable.ic_lists), 0, true, userId, true);

                        categoriesList.add(newGroup);
                        categoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Category added: " + categoryName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        // Save the category in Firestore
                        FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        firestore.collection("categories").add(newGroup)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> {
                                    // Successfully added to Firestore
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Category saved in Firestore", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    // Save the category in SharedPreferences
                                    saveCategoryToSharedPreferences(categoryName);
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                                    // Failed to add to Firestore
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                });

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TaskActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("categoryName", categoryName);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User not authenticated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a category name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


        dialog.show();
    }


private void saveCategoryToSharedPreferences(String categoryName) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("categories", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> categoriesSet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("categories", new HashSet<>());
        categoriesSet.add(categoryName);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("categories", categoriesSet).apply();
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "this data doesn't disappear"? It is deleted from the database? What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: It's a Todolist, The user add category then inside category user add tasks. When the user log out, the category disappear in app, however in firebase it still available.  I don't get errors in logcat. What I want to achieve is that, when user log out, then login again the category should be still available

Comment: I cannot see the issue at first glance. However, since you work with Java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication). This code does, exactly what you're looking for.